# Get records from third table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, group-concat

I have three tables, and duplicate column names also :) I want to join albums to products and images to albums. Images are many. Trying such query, it gives me duplicate products. Is there a chance to grab everything in one query?

```
        SELECT
        *, p.name as nazwa, a.name as nazwa_al, i.name as obrazek
        FROM products p
        JOIN 
        albums a on p.album_id=a.id
        JOIN
          (SELECT *, images.name AS nazwa_im FROM images ORDER BY images.order ASC) i
        ON i.album_id=a.id
        ORDER BY p.order ASC
```

**Products**

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| album_id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Albums**

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Images**

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| alt      | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| album_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| order    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

For the sake of simplicity, I don't want to modify structure of db. The easiest solution for me would be: one product=>one album=>many images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use joins and use aliases to solve duplicate name error.

You can use distint or group by have results aligned as per same product id.

```
SELECT
*, p.name as nazwa, a.name as nazwa_al, i.name as obrazek
FROM 
products p
JOIN 
albums a on p.album_id = a.id
JOIN
images i ON i.album_id = a.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.order ASC
```

You need to use **`group_concat`** if multiple rows on right side.

```
SELECT
*, p.name as nazwa, a.name as nazwa_al, group_concat(i.name) as obrazek
FROM 
products p
JOIN 
albums a on p.album_id = a.id
JOIN
images i ON i.album_id = a.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.order ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. It gave me syntax error, I had to move group by before order by, and now it also gave me only one image "obrazek" - thats the i.name

Comment: Forgot. Not tested query. Updated query. Is it helping? or need help?

Comment: @cssBlaster21895: Check my updated answer? Let me know if it works?

Comment: You can't have two `as` aliases on the same column. So either `as barcodes` or `as obrazek`, but not both.

Comment: @Barmar: Typo by copy paste :(. Sorry. Updated answer. Is there any bug now?